# Changing Chinese visa from old UK passport to new

Tags: visas, passports, china

I currently work in China on a Z visa. My UK passport has only one page remaining and I have plans to travel over the next year. I am thinking of renewing my UK passport this week whilst I am back in the UK for the Christmas holidays.

How will this affect my China visa? Is it still possible to travel with both passports? Or will the Chinese authorities require me to give up my new passport for a change over of the visa?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=cn&SECTION=vi&SUBSECTION=ai&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Valid visas or resident permits in expired passports are
>     accepted if holding a new valid passport of the same
>     nationality. The personal information on both passports must
>   be the same.

So **yes**, you can use a combination of a valid passport and expired passport with your residence permit and/or visa.

In any case, it is strongly recommended for you to transfer your residence permit (not the visa) to your new passport for convenience. This is done at the nearest Exit & Entry Administration office

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with Chinese customs in Shanghai a few minutes ago. They told me that it is acceptable to travel on two passports if the visa in the old passport is still valid. However, the Chinese Embassy in Australia said it depends which port a person uses to gain access to the People's Republic.